# How to deal with a question that contains an answer by the poster on the question itself

Tags: support

Consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383904/cant-get-date-from-nsdateformatter-with-date-2012-11-21-035739-04).

The OP posted a question. The question received several answers from other people. The OP edits the question and says "sorry, found the error", and posts the answer, not as an official answer, but in the question body.

What to do with questions like that? Vote to close (on what reason?), flag? what?

Comment: Edit the "answer" out of the question, and comment asking them to post an answer in the answer field if none of the current answers answers their question. If the question isn't otherwise off-topic, no reason to close it.

Comment: The **wrong** way to handle it is to post your own answer, with a direct copy/paste of what the poster wrote (which is what you just did), without making it CW. The *correct* way to handle it, IMO, is to roll back the poster's edit and leave them a comment about the proper way to self-answer, with a link to the appropriate topic in the help center.

Comment: @KenWhite - if rolling back is the correct way, it will leave the question without any answer. At least the question has an answer embedded in the question. I am not sure if I have admin power to roll back an edit, anyway.

Comment: You're at 10K, which means you have the ability to rollback the edit. I described the proper way to do it (IMO), which is to give the poster a chance to self-answer. If they choose not to do so, and you feel you know the answer to the question asked, *write your own answer*. Posting as you have means you can gain reputation from copy/pasting the answer from the poster, which is simply wrong (it's taking credit and gaining from plagiarizing another person's answer). Plagiarizing (taking the work of others to earn from it) is worse than leaving the question without an answer.

Comment: And as far as what you do and don't have privileges to do here (like rollback edits), see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 6):

Edit the answer out of the question.  If the OP's answer was original, and not just using one of the existing answers, then post the answer as an answer, citing the OP as the author of that content.

You should not be voting to close the question just because an answer is edited into the question.

Comment: Ok, but if the OP does not accept the answer nobody will know that the answer I have added is the correct one.

Comment: @SpaceDog That's just entirely not true.  An answer doesn't need to be accepted for readers to find it, look at it, or determine that it's the correct answer.

Comment: OK, but the eye always search for the checkmark...

Comment: @SpaceDog So anytime you're looking for an answer to a question, if there's no accepted answer, even if there are a bunch of other upvotes answers, you just leave and assume that none of the answers could possibly be valid because they're not accepted?  You're saying that nobody, ever, reads any answer that isn't accepted?  Sorry, but no.  People may be more likely to try an accepted answer first, if there is one,  but that doesn't mean that they never look at any non-accepted answers.

Comment: I'd agree with @Servy here; Personally, I pay no attention to the checkmark and in fact, sometimes I find the non-accepted answers most helpful.